# Core data NOT IN clause for multiple properties

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I want to fetch a records based on NOT IN clause with multiple properties but core data is returning empty result. Below is the predicate I am using

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (id in %@ && field2 in %@ && field3 in %@)
```

I am not getting any errors so I assume syntax is right but core data returning empty result set.

Comment: Do you mean `(NOT d in %@) && (NOT field2 in %@) && (NOT field3 in %@)`?

Comment: tried it but no result

Comment: When you try the three condition one by one, do you get the expected results?

Comment: turned out query is working properly, it was a database design issue

Comment: Nevertheless, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try using `NSCompoundPredicate` `notPredicateWithSubpredicate` - https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscompoundpredicate/1409462-init